# Best way to test a Guava Supplier

Tags: java, guava

If I am using `Supplier` in conjunction with a `Suppliers::memoize(Supplier<T> delegate)` what is the best way to test it?

For example, say I have the following:

```
private static final Supplier<String> ENVIRONMENT_SUPPLIER = Suppliers.memoize(new Supplier<String>() {
    @Override
    public String get() {
        String value = "";// actually something time consuming
        return value;
    }
});
```

The most obvious way to me seems to be to extract the Supplier into its own (inner) class and test that. For some reason this just seems a bit ugly to me and will look a bit silly when I finally upgrade to Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Couple options here.

First, you could declare `ENVIRONMENT_SUPPLIER` as default scope. In this case, the test (which should be in the same package) would have access to it and could test it.

Second, and probably better, if it is a complicated class that does time-consuming work, it would be a great idea to break it into its own class. This not only allow access for testing but also allows you to use a mock when testing the wrapping class. Since it is already implementing an interface (`Supplier`) it would be very easy to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I actually made a slight mistake with the original question and ```ENVIRONMENT_SUPPLIER``` is actually already package private and annotated with ```@VisibleForTesting``` to signify it's only defined that way for testing. I really used wanted to know if there was a better to test the business logic in the ```Supplier``` rather than extracting it out to another class but I guess there is not.

thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you need to extract it to another class. If your issue is the fact that the result is `memoized` the declare the non-memoized instance of the `Supplier` as its own field and test that.

Comment: By extracting it to its own class that's what i meant.

Comment: So just as an FYI, by making it a field you are able to test it but cannot mock it. My making it is own class (not an anonymous inner class) and injecting it, you could them mock it which would be nice since it does `something time consuming`.